# PS3 restore backup restores no data

Tags: ps3, technical-issues

My PS3's blu-ray drive died recently, so I performed a backup with the Backup Utility and sent my console in for repair.

About a week later I received a replacement PS3 from Sony and have attempted to restore using my backup. But, the backup utility has restored **NO DATA**!

I have tried logging in to PSN and attempting the restore again, but the end result is the same.

I'm aware that some data cannot be restored, especially since Sony has replaced my original PS3 with a refurbished one, but surely I should see something restored! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've had a similar issue where a backup who seemingly succeeded failed to restore some data on the same console. Specifically copy-protected saves failed to restore. I would advise you contact Sony support with this issue, as it's seemingly impossible to extract data from their console backups. Maybe they could help you.

Comment: I (the OP) have answered this question myself, but if anyone provides a better answer I'd be happy to mark that one correct instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than try to work out what happened or how to fix the restore process, I just started fresh with my new PS3.

I can't stress how useful the PSN+ cloud service is. Without it you can re-download your games, but not your saves. With it you have a nearly all-encompassing backup solution.

The PSN+ cloud service does not back up saved games from PS1, PS2 or minis though, so be sure and copy those from your old system to a USB device while you still can.

Answer (score -1):

put the new hard drive in, start the ps3, turn on the external, go in to the back up utility, tell it to start the back up, choose the folder, it will say it's going to restart, turn off the external, wait for the ps3 to start, turn on the external, see if it sees the backup.

Comment: The backup itself was successfully completed, and the new PS3 could see the backup. The restore seemed to complete normally (albeit a bit too quickly) but nothing was actually restored.