# PlayStation 3 wireless controllers won't connect to the system, screen won't even turn on

Tags: ps3, technical-issues

I got a new game for the PS3 recently and was hoping to try it out yesterday, but to my surprise, when I turned on my PS3, two things happened:

1. The controllers wouldn't connect at all.
2. The screen started up, but never went to the menu.

I pressed the PS button on both of my two controllers and plugged both of them into the console separately, but to no avail. Today, I went to check on it and now the screen won't even turn on. Now I'm really worried because that means that it's not just a problem with the controllers, but with my PS3. I've had my PS3 since late December 2007, so I'm really hoping that my PS3 isn't having problems after just four years.

Now I've been trying to find solutions online and all of them that I've found so far have to do with holding the power button for 10 seconds. I've already tried this and it hasn't helped. Now I don't want to go to any drastic measures unless there is NO OTHER WAY of fixing it.

So I ask of you all: What is wrong with my PS3? How do I fix it?

Comment: do they work when playing other games? -- wait, the screen doesnt even go to the Xmedia menu? its green? that sounds more like your ps3 took a dump man.

Comment: Does the system turn on fully when you use the system's power button?

Comment: @Adanion Yes, it does, but it doesn't go to the menu.

Comment: @Adanion Actually, I just went to check on my PS3 just now and now the screen isn't even appearing at all.

Comment: I assume the TV is in working order? All the connections are solid? Have to try reseeding the cables? Also, just to cover all the right bases, you're on the right input?

Comment: @Sorean Definitely.

Comment: See my original comment. That is all.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, your PS3 is as good as dead. Even if you manage to get it working in the short term, it won't last much longer in the long term.

I believe you have two options:

- If you **don't** need to recover anything from your current PS3 (ie. if you've been using the PSN+ cloud service to backup your saved games), contact Sony and send your PS3 in for repair.
- If you **do** need to recover data from your current PS3, you will need to have the PS3 repaired by a 3rd party service. *Do not send it to Sony, as their policy is to format all received hard disks for privacy reasons. Sony may also send you a replacement, refurbished unit rather than return your original one, making your Backup Utility backup almost useless.*

If you do manage to get your current PS3 working, you might be able to try a third option:

- Buy a new PS3 and transfer your data over using the [Data Transfer Utility](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/settings/transferutility.html). Do whatever you wish (repair/sell/etc) with your old PS3.

Don't bother with the Backup Utility. This is really only useful when you are upgrading the hard disk and may restore very little or even no data when restored to a different PS3 unit, [as was my recent experience](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53116/ps3-restore-backup-restores-no-data).

Best of luck.

Comment: I would agree, I was able to get mine back up and working after a YLOD but less than a month in I lost it again. It also took quite a while to fix so I was out playing time for months and lost valuable  time with PSN+. @YellowMegaMan Does the Data Transfer Utility work if the PS3 won't boot?

Comment: @kwelch: No, both PS3s must be functioning to be able to use Data Transfer Utility.

Comment: That is what I thought. Thanks! I am stuck with that now.