# Is it possible to get data off of a dead PS3?

Tags: ps3

Is it possible to get the data off of the hard drive of a PlayStation 3 that has crashed? I have already voided the warranty so I am not worried about that and I have access to quite a few tools.

I have a new PlayStation and a few saves that were not backed up. I am not worried about them but if it is possible I would love to get it moved over.

The old PlayStation will not turn on at all and I think I am going to have to pull the drive. My main concern is if I am able to transfer the files without running into any issues. I have heard that some of the stuff is specific to each PlayStation, is that true?

Comment: If it is a YLOD, see [this related question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74154/how-do-i-get-a-dead-bulky-ps3-to-work-again-momentarily-at-least)

Comment: Great link. I actually have already passed that point and it has died yet again. My next adventure is resurrecting an xbox even though I will probably only use it for game development.

Comment: @kewlch: The Xbox's can have the same issue as the PS3 *(it usually shows up either the same way as the PS3, or as the Xbox seemingly running fine, but not showing any video whatsoever on any of the output ports, even after [resetting the display settings](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911059/en-gb))*.  Keep in mind that any solution would only be temporary, though - if you're looking for an XBox for development and the one you have has this issue, you'd be better off just buying a new one.

Comment: The xbox issue is with the disc drive so it should be a simpler fix. Worst case the disc drive doesn't work and I just use it as a development or media center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to get data off a PS3's hard disk if the PS3 is dead.

Transplanting the hard disk into a new PS3 doesn't work because the hard disk data is tied to the old PS3. The new PS3 will only allow you to format the drive, not access the data.

See my answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/54843/1613) for options.

Comment: @kwelch: I see you've already seen the link I've provided here. I put it here anyway for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I swapped my PS3 old HDD with my PS3 new HDD without any issues. However getting the data from my original old stock HDD to my old 500GB HDD was an issues as i could not read it as an external hdd on my computer, if this help.

Comment: Unfortunately my new PS3 has twice the HDD space so I would not want to revert back to the old one. Good to know though. Thanks

Comment: oh, allow me to explain more. I upgraded my first ps3 with 500gb, then swapped that one into the second ps3 i bought, which was still smaller than 500gb (240 or something...)